# How to change the device language in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on RTL in xamarin forms. I need to show Right to left flow direction on click of a button.  I was working from morning. I didn't get the solution. I got only language changes means if I want Arabic I can do by using multilingual plugin. But I need to change the flow direction. How to do it?

Comment: It looks like this official video is you want. (https://youtu.be/f2lQ5yw3iiU)

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT, I got the solution on that day. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the `FlowDirection` in your page / visual elements.

```
<ContentPage ... FlowDirection="{x:Static Device.FlowDirection}"> />
```

Or, if you don't want to set based on the device language, you can just set one of these available options

```
public enum FlowDirection
    {
        MatchParent = 0,
        LeftToRight = 1,
        RightToLeft = 2,
    }
```

You can read more in the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/right-to-left)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want in button click to change the device language to arabic and the view direction to RightToLeft. Is it possible. Please let me know.

Comment: Yes. What have you implemented so far?

Comment: I'm able to change the language in application level. But what about the RTL flow direction.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Manifest file, enable RTL like below

```
<application android:label="MyApp" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <!--others-->
</application>
```

Note that RTL is available in android from API 17+

In the iOS project, enable Arabic culture by adding it to the CFBundleLocalizations in info.plist file-

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>ar</string>
</array>
```

In the Forms project, set flow direction (by default it is Right oriented) to ContentPage, Labels etc.

```
FlowDirection="{x:Static Device.FlowDirection}"
```

Setting Arabic culture will automatically change the page's Flow direction to RightToLeft if it's specified like above.

Comment: @shiblue, Sorry for ask the wrong question. I wanted in Button click. Means if i have rtl button or ltr button on click of it should change the flow direction.